# Stronger bond between GoPro mount and helmet?

Tags: maintenance, electronic-gear, helmets

I used a regular curved helmet mount for my GoPro on my recent snowboarding trip, which comes self-adhesive.  At one point I fell on my back and hit the back of my helmet, the shock of which unglued the mount from the helmet.  Luckily, I was able to find it as it wasn't too far.

Is there a way to make the adhesive bond between the mount and the helmet stronger?  Should I add some super glue over the existing layer of the peel-off adhesive surface?

Comment: You might want to concern that making the bond stronger might not be what you want. The camera on its mount is a thing sticking away from your head that makes a nice but hazardous lever to act on your head in case of a fall. There are already voices that suspect that helmet mounted cameras could lead to an increased injure rate for that reason. So having the connection between helmet and camera as the weakest breaking point in the system might be in your favour to protect your neck from damage.

Comment: If you're ok with neck injuries, I'd recommend Gorilla glue over super glue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Sugru](https://sugru.com/) is the bond you are looking for.  I use it for lots of uses and it will work ideally for your needs.

Simply Google Sugru and be amazed.

Comment: WOW, that seems awesome

Comment: Thanks @Liam - I was using a phone and the link addition seemed like too much work :-)